# undetected chrome extension with Opera

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, opera, navigator, opera-extension

I have just installed Opera and add three extensions, none of them has this id :
chrome-extension://bgpmiljelfnilfcfmoppijdkmccbccel/isolated-first.jst
Does anybody know which plugin is hidden behind this extension?

Expect to find the name of a chrome extension or opera plugin I find when I check ajax request in the navigator network panel

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to one of Opera's integrated extensions, which would explain why it isn't being displayed in your extension list.

Opening `opera://extensions/?id=bgpmiljelfnilfcfmoppijdkmccbccel` should display the extension's settings page which would provide you with more details about this extension.

Opera has installed hidden and non-removable extensions like this for promotions in the past, [this forum post](https://forums.opera.com/topic/46587/amazon-promotion-extension/4?_=1692997981558&lang=en-US) lists some of them.

Comment: Did you try to follow this link? It does not show any details. Instead, it redirects to the extension list page.